# Access apache inside ubuntu container

Tags: docker

I have apache installed inside a running ubuntu:14.04 container. How to access this in the browser of the host machine? The address showing inside the container is, 172.17.0.2. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the apache image exposes the port 80, but you need config this in run command (-p):

docker run -d -p 80:80 httpd

The first number is port of Docker Host and the second one is port of container. This configuration will map all connections to port tcp 80 of docker host to the same port of container.

After that you can access your application in your browser, using 127.0.0.1, localhost or other IP Address of your interface.

Comment: Do you have any idea on this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397113/apache-page-retains-after-exiting-docker-container ??

Answer (score 2):

By default, the [apache httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) image [exposes the port 80](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/3ea3760ef8d264ac7539ec6db9ce9c0b0665a192/2.4/Dockerfile#L64)

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-apache-app -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

So `http://localhost` should be enough.

In your case, make sure:

- the httpd is actually running (`docker exec -it <yourContainer> bash`: `ps -eaf`),
- you have mapped the port you are running Apache in your container to the host (-p 80:80 for instance).