# Apache page retains after exiting docker container

Tags: apache, docker

I'm new to docker. I tried executing the following docker command to created a container,

```
docker run -d -p 9999:80 httpd
```

After this, when i visited the URL http://127.0.0.1:9999/, It loads with "It works!" message. So, to change the message, I went inside the httpd container and changed the value of /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html (Hope, that is the correct location) to `<html><body><h1>It works at port 9999!</h1></body></html>`.

But still it is showing the same old message and the weird part is it is still showing up after removing the container. Am i doing anything wrong or is this coming from any cache or something?

Please help.

**Edit**: I found it is due to browser cache and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You did a modification to a running container, but if you want to see it, you have to

`docker commit -t my_apache_modified`

your container, and then launch your new image, with a

`docker run -d -p 9999:80 my_apache_modified`

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/

Keep in mind that the preferred way is to modify your Dockerfile, and build a new image

Comment: I tried your solution, it still shows the old message only on the old port 9999. But if we modify the port to something else, it is loading the new content. Any idea??

Comment: you have to stop your "old" container, or start the commited image to another port

Comment: I stopped and even removed the container. But still getting the page loaded at http://127.0.0.1:9999/ which is really weird. But not sure how? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error here.

Try that:

> docker run -d --name httpdtest -p 9999:80 httpd
>
> docker exec -it httpdtest bash
>
> echo "test" >> htdocs/index.html

And try to see in your browser. (http://127.0.0.1:9999)

Comment: The string "test" don't appear too?

Comment: No it is still the same, even I verified the content of the file and it has the updated content.